# How to invert an IndexedSeq in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Having an IndexedSeq, how to iterate it from the end to the beginning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call `reverseIterator` if you just want to iterate it from end to beginning.  If you want to apply a map, `reverseMap`.  `foldLeft` and `foldRight` traverse in opposite directions, so each can be thought of as the other on the reversed list; likewise with `reduceRight` and `scanRight`.  There are a bunch of `last` methods to find things near the end instead of the beginning.  Anything else, and `reverse` (to recreate the whole collection) or `.view.reverse.whatever` if you don't want to duplicate the collection in memory.  For a simple `foreach`, `reverseIterator` will generally do the trick.

Comment: I did not recall such a method existed! I'm so glad I didn't have time to answer questions that day... :-)

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral - I remembered it because I was rather disappointed it exists at all; I prefer simplicity in my collections interfaces than having every convenience method I can imagine.

Answer (score 4):

You can just reverse it:

```
scala> val x = IndexedSeq(1,2,3,4)
x: IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> x.reverse.foreach(println)
4
3
2
1
```

Or, depending on what you're doing while you're iterating, a `foldRight` might be what you want.  `foldRight` is a fold that moves from right to left through the collection.

```
scala> x.foldRight(0){ (item, total) => println("adding "+item); total + item }
adding 4
adding 3
adding 2
adding 1
res121: Int = 10
```

Comment: Thanks. I've somehow missed the obvious `reverse` while looking through the methods list.